# bash for loop not working as expected

Tags: bash

I have six openvswitches that I have created using mininet.I want to dump the flow tables using a very simple bash script.For some reason this doesn't seem to be working.

```
for i in `sudo ovs-vsctl list-br` ; do {`sudo ovs-ofctl dump-flows $i`}  ; done
```

gives the output

```
{NXST_FLOW: command not found
{NXST_FLOW: command not found
{NXST_FLOW: command not found
{NXST_FLOW: command not found
{NXST_FLOW: command not found
{NXST_FLOW: command not found
```

However if I do

```
for i in `sudo ovs-vsctl list-br` ; do echo $i  ; done
```

I get the below output.

s1
s2
s3
s4
s5
s6

By the way I am able to do

```
sudo ovs-ofctl dump-flows s1
```

and get the right information.

What is wrong with my bash script.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why use the backticks? Just do

```
for i in `sudo ovs-vsctl list-br` ; do sudo ovs-ofctl dump-flows $i ; done
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

for i in `sudo ovs-vsctl list-br`; do sudo ovs-ofctl dump-flows $i; done

Answer (score 0):

You're using [command substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution) and [command grouping](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Grouping) all at once.

You told bash to run the command (the backticks) and then treat the output as another command to run.